# Combine different parts of sprites to form a single sprite in cocos2d-x in ios game using c++

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I am starter in cocos2d-x.I have multiple sprites of arms legs eyes etc.i want to create a single sprite ,suppose a human out of it who has arms,legs,eyes,head,body etc.How to do it..As i have to animate them and make the human walking and also i have to kill it on touch.Any one here please tell me the logic in cocos2d-x using c++

Comment: You can also look into Spine : http://esotericsoftware.com - it is a great animation tool, though not free :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way of using it.We can use cocostudio also and export the file as JSON
Refer to this link 
http://upyun.cocimg.com/CocoStudio/helpdoc/v1.0.0.0/en/index.html

Answer (score 0):

CocosBuilder can be used for assembling the body parts. By laying down each sprite to its own layer, you can also animate them, create different animations for walking, dying.

Tutorials :
http://www.raywenderlich.com/23996/introduction-to-cocosbuilder
http://www.plungeinteractive.com/blog/2012/10/29/using-cocosbuilder-on-cocos2d-x-games/